# Where does this Return of the King quote come from?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

Is there a page reference for this quote from Return of the King?

> The Hobbits Frodo and Bilbo (and later Samwise), although of mortal kind, by virtue of having borne the One Ring also bore a weariness in their bones. But in Middle-Earth they could find no relief from this.

Comment: page numbers will be different across various publications of the material

Comment: Wait...you have an exam that asks what page number a LOTR excerpt is from? What class is this? What school is this?

Comment: Also that's not actually a quote from the book, it's a comment from [a question on this very web site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13518/why-did-all-the-ringbearers-leave-middle-earth-in-the-end/51477).

Comment: I think this is too broad. True, there are a definite number of editions of LOTR, but still... On a side note - I don't know the details but if you can remember the quote and chapter, page number should be unnecessary info. If your teacher says it's mandatory, you may want to tell him what was said above - the page will vary with editions, and it's not that much relevant...

Comment: @KyleDoyle Sounds more like they are using SE to help write a report, and are trying to find where in the books that came from (though it seems like it just came from another SE user).

Comment: Ah... Then I stand by my close vote, although it's now _unclear_ what's that question is asking, instead of being too broad. Roger, please [edit] your question to clarify if what @JMac postulated above is true, otherwise we can't really presume what you're getting at :)

Answer (score 3):

The quote in question is not from any edition of Return of the King, it's part of [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13520/20774) to [this question on SFF:SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13518/why-did-all-the-ringbearers-leave-middle-earth-in-the-end/51477) asking why various characters left Middle Earth.

It would appear that the sentences are original writings by user [Mark Beadles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4025/mark-beadles).

Comment: Oh. I thought it was from the book! Does the book mention Frodo leaving Middle-earth? I know he was physically exhausted from carrying the Ring and wanted to tie this in with a quote for a degree exam tomorrow  “Anything that causes stress endangers life, unless it is met by adequate adaptive responses; conversely, anything that endangers life causes stress and adaptive responses”. 
(Selye, 1950, p. 1383)

Comment: Thank you Valorum & Kyle!