# Source for Frodo/Gandalf exchange about wounds in "The Return of the King"

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, quotes, the-return-of-the-king

Could someone kindly tell me exactly where in the book this quote is found? I need it for an exam tomorrow.

> 'Are you in pain, Frodo?' said Gandalf quietly as he rode by Frodo's side.
>
> 'Well, yes I am,' said Frodo. 'It's my shoulder. The wound aches, and the memory of darkness is heavy on me. It was a year ago today.'
>
> 'Alas! There are some wounds that cannot be wholly cured.' said Gandalf.

Comment: As I posted on [your earlier question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/213558/98028) (its first revision at least), I think this is too broad. True, there are a definite number of editions of LOTR, but still... On a side note - I don't know the details but if you can remember the quote and chapter, page number should be unnecessary info. If your teacher says it's mandatory, you may want to tell him what was said above - the page will vary with editions, and it's not that much relevant...

Comment: If you've read the book you can narrow it down quite easily. When and where would Gandalf _ride_ next to Frodo indeed.

Comment: ...and that it was a year after Frodo was wounded narrows it down quite a bit. I believe most editions of LOTR and wikis have [a day-by-day timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7304/what-is-the-timeline-for-the-lord-of-the-rings-trilogy), so you can work out exactly what was happening.

Comment: Thank you Jenayah, Amarth & DC! May the road rise to meet you and the wind always at your back ;)

Comment: I believe that, with the latest edit, the question is not too broad. It can be reasonably answered by saying what chapter the quote comes from and about where in that chapter it occurs (information that is include in the answer by Voldemort's Wrath).

Answer (score 1):

## Beginning of Chapter 7 (Homeward Bound)...

This happens to be, in my edition, page **325**, though is probably different in yours because there can be many different editions. I suggest reading the Table of Contents to determine this.

Here's an excerpt:

> Chapter 7
>
> Homeward Bound
>
> At last the hobbits had their faces turned towards home. They were eager now to see the Shire again; but at first they rode only slowly,  for  Frodo  had  been  ill  at  ease.  When  they  came  to  the Ford of Bruinen, he had halted, and seemed loth to ride into the stream; and they noted that for a while his eyes appeared not to see them or things about him. All that day he was silent. It was the sixth of October.
>
> ‘Are you in pain, Frodo?’ said Gandalf quietly as he rode by Frodo’s side.
>
> ‘Well, yes I am,’ said Frodo. ‘It is my shoulder. The wound aches, and the memory of darkness is heavy on me. It was a year ago today.’
>
> ‘Alas! there are some wounds that cannot be wholly cured,’said Gandalf.

*(Note that I am answering this to help you out, but it is still a very poor question!)*

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!! Peace & prosperity in your life!

Comment: @Roger Please press the check mark underneath the up and down arrows to accept my answer if it is correct!