# In Peter Jackson’s Lord of the Rings Films, what is the eventual fate of Samwise?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, the-lord-of-the-rings

[Reference this related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13518/why-did-all-the-ringbearers-leave-middle-earth-in-the-end) for context.

In the film adaptation, the ship that Frodo and Bilbo took was the last ship to leave for the Undying Lands.

So, in-universe of the films, what eventually happens to film Sam?

I’m primarily looking for either authoritative or canonical validation, but speculative sources are also beneficial to understanding this question.

Comment: *"So, in-universe of the films, what eventually happens to film Sam?"* We don't see other than him going home so not sure what "authortative" answer you could expect.

Comment: @Paulie_D Genre of fantasy and sci-fi film is not devoid of derivative works, or film creative team statements. Searching just Amazon books for “Lord of the Rings films” returns nearly 1,000 different books based on the films; is there a licensed book or perhaps director, screenwriter, script-writer, producer, actor statements which shed light on the character’s fate? Alternately, if “returning home” is the only authoritative proof of his fate, what are the lifespans of film Hobbits that could facilitate a canonical answer for his fate?

Comment: You're asking about the movie *specifically* so any anything else would not be "in-universe" since it's not in the movie.

Comment: @Paulie_D I’m asking about the movie events; any movie derivative works such as a licensed “Guide to Peter Jackson’s Lord of the Rings Films” which establishes Sam’s eventual fate is fair game. As are any confirmations of film’s creators discussing film events and their creative intent. As stated in the question, either authoritative or canonical answers are primarily intended, however speculative sourcing may also be beneficial in understanding the best answer.

Comment: I'm just listening to the commentaries now. I don't *remember* any mention of Sam's fate but I'm rechecking.

Comment: Frodo suggests that: “My dear Sam. You cannot always be torn in two. You have to be one and whole for many years. You have so much enjoy and to be and to do. Because Sam, your part in the journey goes on.” We are then introduced to a Sam’s new son named Frodo, suggesting some bit of time jump to future after ring was destroyed and/or others departed.

Comment: Seems implied by the end of the film that it’s the same or similar to the end of the books and they just disinterested want to keep the audience in their seats for that much longer.

Comment: @ToddWilcox So are you aware of how Sam makes his way to Undying Lands?  Via different path; did they send another “last ship?”

Comment: What about the movie ever implied it was the "Last Ship"?

Comment: @IG_42 Good point. I took that for granted in the referenced question, answer and comments. But that’s not explicit. 

Comment: If you read closely, it's only his descendants who choose to believe he took a ship to the undying lands. What actually happened after the last time he rode from The Shire is not recorded or known for certain.

Comment: You want to know what happens after the movie, but don't want any Tolkien source material used as citation?

Comment: @MeatTrademark I’m primarily looking for either authoritative or canonical validation, but speculative sources are also beneficial to understanding this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing in the films suggests that Sam does anything other than live out his life with his family in the Shire.

The final scene of the *Return of the King* movie is the same prosaic final scene as in the book - Sam comes home to Bag End after seeing Frodo off to Lindon, he sits down, Rosie puts a child in his lap, and Sam says *"Well, I'm back"*.

Peter Jackson didn't make anything out of the post-War of the Ring material in the Appendices, which is where the idea that Sam followed Frodo into the West comes from.

Jackson also elided enough from the original books that we shouldn't assume that any extra material from the books pertains to movie continuity.

Comment: Yes. This appears to be the canonical version of a correct answer.